# Writing formula in VBA results in Compile Error - Double Quotes

Tags: vba, excel, double-quotes

I'm working on an Excel VBA Macro.

I must write a formula inside a cell.

The formula I'm referring to is `CONTA.SE()`. It behaves  in the same way as `COUNTIF()` does. I guess that it is the `COUNTIF()` version for Excel in italian.

To be more precise the formula I want to implement is:

```
=CONTA.SE(Report!E:E;"<20")
```

so that it works on cells values from **E2** to the last non-empty cell.

I guess I'm having trouble because of the double quotes.

I've tried many solutions as, for example:

```
Cells(5, 2).Formula = "=CONTA.SE(Report!E2:E" & rowCount & ";" & Chr(34) & "<20" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

or:

```
Cells(5, 2).Formula = "=CONTA.SE(Report!E2:E" & rowCount & ";" & """<20""" & ")"
```

The error message I got is:

> run-time Error 1004:
>     Error defined by the Object or the Application.

Can anyone, please, tell my how write it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Formula` uses the english version of the formulas. If you want to use the localized formula (eg italian) you must use `.FormulaLocal`.

So either localized:

```
Cells(5, 2).FormulaLocal = "=CONTA.SE(Report!E2:E" & rowCount & ";" & Chr(34) & "<20" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

or english

```
Cells(5, 2).Formula = "=COUNTIF(Report!E2:E" & rowCount & "," & Chr(34) & "<20" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Note that the localized (italian) form only works when used in an italian Excel, but the english version would work on any Excel. So using the english version in VBA is recommended. Using the english formula in VBA will automatically convert it into the correct localization form in the cell (the user will not notice any difference).

Also note that the english separator is `,` while the italian (and most european) separator is `;`.

Comment: Dear Pᴇʜ, I do thank you for your answer. I've replaced Formula with FormulaLocal, and now it works. You've saved my day! Ps: I think I've tried using the english version of the formula, but I got errors. I'm gonna try again. Thank you again, really

Comment: The english should work. Did you notice to replace the `;` in the formula by `,` for the english version?

Comment: I read wrong, and I thought you were referring to the comma in Cells (). Perhaps you are referring to the semicolon in the formula. Tomorrow I try and I think it will work. Thanks again Pᴇʜ; really.